# Python 2.7 created with altinstall needs to access scipy dependencies

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I recently updated my CentOS6 server from Python 2.6 to 2.7, by leaving the system version alone and using the altinstall method.

```
# yum groupinstall "Development tools"
# yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel

# wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tar.bz2
# tar xf Python-2.7.3.tar.bz2
# cd Python-2.7.3
# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
# make && make altinstall
```

Then I installed distribute and through it, virtual env

```
# wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.35.tar.gz
# tar xf distribute-0.6.35.tar.gz
# cd distribute-0.6.35
# python2.7 setup.py install

# easy_install-2.7 virtualenv
# virtualenv-2.7 --distribute someproject
New python executable in someproject/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in someproject/bin/python
Installing distribute...................done.
Installing pip................done.
# source someproject/bin/activate
(someproject)# python --version
Python 2.7.3
(someproject)#
```

Everything works great, I activate my virtualenv and install anything I need there, with one exception, those damn scipy and numpy modules!!
When I try to instal scipy, I get the following error:

```
error: 
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
```

I did loads of research and reading, and it seems that the problem is not with the virtualenv settings but with the python2.7 installation which doesn't seem to be using those libraries at all. It also seems that it is really difficult to recompile them for just this version of Python. Is this the case or I am missing something here?

Do you know how I can point my newly installed python2.7 version to use those libraries? Or just point me to the correct direction?

**EDIT**: The -dev packages that include those dependencies have already been installed in the past for python2.6, however they cannot be accessed for the new version created with altinstall.

Comment: I'm not familiar with rh/centos - but try installing the -dev packages of blas from the repo, this should install all the build requirements then you can compile it for yourself.

Comment: I have already installed them in the past and they work for python2.6. How can the new python version access them though?

Comment: What did you install exactly? centos typically has binary package and then the -dev equivalents; if you installed the binary packages it was compiled against the reference version of Python and would not have installed the build libraries.

Comment: It has been a while, but I guess I did something along those lines `sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have BLAS on your machine and you know where it is, you can use it to build scipy by setting 'BLAS' environment variable beforehand. E.g.,

```
export BLAS=/path/to/libblas.so
```

A pedagogical note: Doing this doesn't point Python2.7 itself to BLAS, as you asked. You are just telling scipy where to find BLAS during the build process. Python itself is blissfully ignorant, and will just use scipy directly once it is built.

Also, scipy.org offers detailed installation instructions for all common Linuxes. My answer is mostly a regurgitation of the information here:

http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/linux.html

Comment: Thanks, what you say make sense, I will give it a try later and come back with some results!

Comment: I should also add that if you don't know where to point 'BLAS', you can just `sudo yum install atlas-devel` before installing scipy. Atlas is a package (only for RedHat Linux, CentOS, Fedora, etc. I think) that contains BLAS.

Comment: `yum install` will not work on the virtualenv and it has already been done, scipy any numpy were working for the older version of Python. What you suggested pointed me to the correct direction though, my configuration needed some additional steps and libraries, but it is working now! A million thanks for the useful advice :)

Comment: I successfully recompiled the original numpy and scipy packages now for an old Fedora (Fedora 11 from year 2009 - similar to CentOS) and the tests passed: `python -c "import numpy; numpy.test()`, similarly for scipy. The package "blas-devel" is really necessary for compiling scipy and numpy, even although "blas" package is not required for running them. `sudo yum install blas-devel`